# Spell casting - How to optimize damage per second : Variation of 0-1 Knapsack

Tags: algorithm, combinations, sequence, backtracking, knapsack-problem

I am trying to make an algorithm that finds the sequence of spell that maximizes the total damage.
**I understood this situation as a 0-1 knapsack problem with cooldown for each item**. However, I couldn't come out with an appropriate algorithm to solve it(except checking all the possible situations).

I have found the exact same question asked 13 years ago, but the answers seemed not enought for me.

This was the original question by aaronfarr

"Imagine we have a wizard that knows a few spells. Each spell has 3 attributes: Damage, cool down time, and a cast time. Pretty standard RPG stuff.

Cooldown time: the amount of time (t) it takes before being able to cast that spell again. A spell goes on "cooldown" the moment it begins casting.

Cast time: the amount of time (t) it takes to use a spell. While the wizard is casting something another spell cannot be cast and it cannot be canceled.

## The question is: How would you maximize damage given different sets of spells?

## (my question is also same)

It is easy to calculate the highest damage per cast time. But what about in situations where it is better to wait then to get "stuck" casting a low damage spell when a much higher one is available?

For example,

Fireball: 3000 damage, 3 second cast time, 6 second cool down.

Frostbolt: 20 damage, 4 second cast time, 4 second cool down.

Fireblast: 3 damage, 3 second cast time, 3 second cool down.

In this case your damage per second is higher if you chose to go for the lower DPCT spell (fireblast) instead of the frostbolt. So we must consider consequences of choosing a spell.

[image: Two spellcasting scenarios in 42 seconds]

(https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/5593/spell-casting-how-to-optimize-damage-per-second)

these are my thoughts for the answers that were written 13 years ago.

1. try using Uniform Cost Search, A*, IDA* - by deft_code
   I have googled about those algorithms(Dijkstra Algorithm together), but thoses seemed to focus on the problem with "Start Point" and "End Point". In my case, the goal is to find the sequence of spell that maximizes the total damage and this seems like combination optimize problem which is not appropriate to solve with them.
2. anserver by aaronfarr himself
   I think the solution he came out with is a type of greedy algorithm with does not guarantee the right answer. **I am looking for an algoritm that guarantees the best answer.**

and these are other algorithms I have tried.

1. Dynamic Programming
   The problem of Dynamic Programming was that I couldn't take cooldown, cast time into an account.
   In DP, it seemed impossible to know which spell was used before.
2. Brute force
   I tried this solution with DFS. Since the number of spells is about 15~25, this took way more time than I expected. This can be the last resort, but I am hoping for something better.

Comment: *"In this case your damage per second is higher if you chose to go for the lower DPCT spell (fireblast) instead of the frostbolt. So we must consider consequences of choosing a spell. "* <<< Can you explain? Frostbolt deals 20 damage and costs only 4+4=8 seconds; Fireblast deals only 3 damage and costs 3+3=6 seconds, 20/8=2.5 is definitely bigger than 3/6=0.5. And that's without mentioning the Fireball which deals a disproportionate 3000 damage for nearly the same casttime+cooldowntime.

Comment: @Stef I'm sorry for causing you confusion. I forgot the to say "In 42s time limit". It's because using Fireblast instead of FrostBolt allows you to cast Fireball one more time. You can see the image description of this by clicking "enter image description here"(I don't know why but I can't put image directly to the body

Comment: @evol1102 Oh, yes. Well in this case, Fireball is so much more powerful than the other two that really you just want to maximise the number of Fireballs that you cast, and *if* you can fit a Fireblast or Frostbolt inbetween, do it, but never sacrifice a Fireball for that.

Comment: If the number of spells that have cooldown time is low, you can use dynamic programming and include the remaining cooldown time of every spell as a parameter. (In your example I consider that Frostbolt and Fireblast don't have cooldown time, since they're already cooled down when they're finished casting) `highest_damage(time=42, fireballcooldown=0) = max( 3000 + highest_damage(time=39, fireballcooldown=3),  20 + highest_damage(time=38, fireballcooldown=0),  3 + highest_damage(time=39, fireballcooldown=0) )`

Comment: @Stef that would work for the example case(or cases with a spell that overwhelms the rest), but I am looking for the one that can deal with all kinds of settings. I found that "Maximize the use of spell with greatest DPCT -> try to maximize the one with next greatest DPCT -> repeat the process until the limit time " sometimes fail to find the best combination

Comment: @evol1102 What is "that" in "that would work" in your last comment?

Comment: @Stef oh I writted the comment before the second comment(the one about DP) appeared on my screen. I feel like the DP with additional parameter may work for my case.

Comment: @evol1102 Note that in this case, instead of filling a dynamic programming array bottom-up as is often done, it might be worth it doing it top-down, since most parameter combinations might be useless. For instance with the small example, we are only going to care about situations where `fireballcooldown=0` or `fireballcooldown=3`; we're never going to encounter situations where `fireballcooldown=2` or `fireballcooldown=1`, so filling an array with those values would be a waste.

Comment: @Stef Thanks for helping me alot. I've gotta try that one right now

Answer (score 4):

At any point in time, the state of the wizard include the remaining cast time on any spell that he is casting, and the list of remaining cooldown times.

He only has to make a decision when the remaining cast time is 0, so we only need to consider those states.

The decision that the wizard must make is to wait or to cast one of the spells with cooldown = 0.  The only thing it makes sense to wait for is the cooldown of the next spell to cast, so the decision that the wizard must make at any decision point is just the next spell to cast, and he will cast it immediately if the cooldown is 0 or after the cooldown time.  The time before the next decision state is the casting time plus remaining cooldown.

So now you can make the graph of states (cooldown lists) and transitions (spell selections), which you can search in various ways, keeping track of DPS.

If you want to find the highest possible *continuous* DPS, then you need to search for the best cycle in this graph.  The simplest way is to start at each reachable state and use DFS to find the best simple path, if any, back to the start.  I'm not entirely sure that's what you're looking for, though.